# javascript/jquery timing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

General issue - if I hover on the links too fast, the element that should of faded out does not and stays on the page.

For this widget, I am creating a rotator. Normally it displays element set A, it just fades out the current div and fades in the next. This all works fine. A second component is some links which when I hover on them, it will stop the rotator and display an element from set B. when i hover off the link, it will have a deplay (i used setTimeout) of maybe 3-4 seconds then resumes the rotator to show element A items.

I have this working as long as I hover over the links at slow speed but when i hover and switch from one link to another at high speed, then i get some divs from element B staying on the page.

I don't have the code with me because it is at work but has anyone seen a similar issue? how can I fix this? I worked on this for a whole day

I think this has something to do with while fading I call the fade again stopping the fade out being called or something like that. but i have tried to put a condition to say if the timeout is still in process, clear the timeout and fade out. I might of coded something wrong but in general has anyone seen this kind of problem?

Comment: Hint 1: use .stop() Hint 2: please post some code.